# Can a sass selector contain a '%' character?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a variable that contains a string value in the form of some percentage  eg. '10%'  I want to use that value to build a class name to add to my html element if the percentage is anything above '0%'. I thought this would be easy using a sass loop but I can't seem to get the class name constructed correctly.
I thought it would look something like this.

```
 @for $i from 1 through 100{
   .highlight-#{$i}% {
       // styling
    }
  }

  .highlight-0% {
      // styling
  }
```

I have tried several variations:

```
.highlight-#{$i + '%'} { // styling }
.highlight-#{$i}${'%'} { // styling }
```

I don't know if this is even possible since '%' may be reserved.

I am adding the html just in case someone can suggest a way to remove the % in there. This is what I would like to be able to do:

```
<tr><td class="pad-10 highlight-${publisher.numViewsPercentage}" align="center">${publisher.numViewsPercentage}</td></tr>
```

Comment: what about changing `%` to `prct`?

Comment: I only have my string value in the html page and I can't change it as it is ultimately used as a display value. It would be ideal if this value was a number and the % was added in the html. I will add what my element looks like maybe there is a suggestion to remove the percentage where the classname is constructed.

Comment: where is publisher.numViewsPercentage?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the % symbol so that it get treated as a string and not an operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only is `%` a reserved character in Sass, the bigger issue is it's not an allowed character in CSS selector names. So even if you could make Sass compile the resulting class names won't be valid and won't work.

For the most part selector names need to use only letters, numbers, underscore and hyphens.

```css
.nopercent {
  color: red;
}

.percent% {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nopercent">
  An element withOUT a percent sign in the class.
</div>
<div class="percent%">
  An element with a percent sign in the class.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

% is a placeholder character in SASS since version 3.2.
You should just use it for "invisible" extendeds.